# Check expression argument of function

Tags: r, function, arguments, expression

When writing functions it is important to check for the type of arguments. For example, take the following (not necessarily useful) function which is performing subsetting:

```
data_subset = function(data, date_col) {

      if (!TRUE %in% (is.character(date_col) | is.expression(date_col))){
        stop("Input variable date is of wrong format")
      }

      if (is.character(date_col)) {
        x <- match(date_col, names(data))
      } else  x <- match(deparse(substitute(date_col)), names(data))

        sub <- data[,x]
}
```

I would like to allow the user to provide the column which should be extracted as character or expression (e.g. a column called "date" vs. just date). At the beginning I would like to check that the input for date_col is really either a character value or an expression. However, 'is.expression' does not work:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object '...' not found
```

Since deparse(substitute)) works if one provides expressions I thought 'is.expression' has to work as well.
What is wrong here, can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not looking for `is.expression` but for `is.name`.

The tricky part is to get the type of `date_col` and to check if it is of type character only if it is *not* of type `name`. If you called `is.character` when it's a name, then it would get evaluated, typically resulting in an error because the object is not defined.

To do this, [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) can be used: In

```
if(!(is.name(substitute(date_col)) || is.character(date_col)))
```

`is.character` is only called if `is.name` returns `FALSE`.

Your function boils down to:

```
data_subset = function(data, date_col) {

  if(!(is.name(substitute(date_col)) || is.character(date_col))) {
     stop("Input variable date is of wrong format") 
  }

  date_col2 <- as.character(substitute(date_col))
  return(data[, date_col2])
}
```

Of course, you could use `if(is.name(…))` to convert only to character when `date_col` is a name.

This works:

```
testDF <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(10), col2 = rnorm(10, mean = 10), col3 = rnorm(10, mean = 50), rnorm(10, mean = 100))

data_subset(testDF, "col1") # ok
data_subset(testDF, col1) # ok
data_subset(testDF, 1) # Error in data_subset(testDF, 1) : Input variable date is of wrong format
```

However, I don't think you should do this. Consider the following example:

```
var <- "col1"
data_subset(testDF, var) #  Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , date_col2) : undefined columns selected

col1 <- "col2"
data_subset(testDF, col1) # Gives content of column 1, not column 2.
```

Though this "works as designed", it is confusing because unless carefully reading your function's documentation one would expect to get `col1` in the first case and `col2` in the second case.

Abusing a [famous quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use non-standard evaluation.”   Now they have two problems.

Hadley Wickham in [Non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html):

> Non-standard evaluation allows you to write functions that are extremely powerful. However, they are harder to understand and to program with. As well as always providing an escape hatch, carefully consider both the costs and benefits of NSE before using it in a new domain.

Unless you expect large benefits from allowing to skip the quotes around the name of the column, don't do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! Haven´t heard about short circuit evaluation so far. ;)
I will drop the possibility to input expressions as arguments. Saving two keystrokes is not worth the possible complications, you´re right.